# 2048 bit-RSA signature on RF type

Tags: rsa, digital-signature, javacard

I'm conducting a key generation test for RSA signature.
An Error occur in case of 2048 bit key generation over contactless interface and I want to know the reason.

My test changes two factors

- key size : 1024 bit, 2048 bit
- interface : contact, contactless

The result of my test is as follows

- 1024 bit, contact interface -> Success
- 1024 bit, contactless interface -> Success
- 2048 bit, contact interface -> Success
- **2048 bit, contactless interface -> FAIL** (Sometimes, Success.)

In the fourth test, the card returns SW `6300` which JCRE returns.

Someone said that an contactless terminal shut off the power when generating 2048 bit key but I'm not sure. Is there anyone who heard about that?

Comment: Have you tried other Cardreaders?

Comment: What do you mean with "In the fourth test, SW 6300 occurs at key generation step which JCRE returns."? Does it do this when it fails? Why do you do key pair generation if you want to test RSA signature generation? Could you show us the code?

Comment: So you are generating 2048-bit keys over a contactless interface?

Comment: @owlstead I didn't implement SW 6300 in my code. So I think it means JCRE returns SW 6300.

Comment: I guess my question is a little confusing for you. So, I modified my question and I hope you understand it exactly.

Comment: So you do *not* create a key pair before you sign in the same APDU?

Comment: The one that is generated *usually* means "authentication failed". It would be pretty strange if that one was generated by the platform, unless the platform is disturbed and a verification check is performed. Even then you would expect an exception, which *should* turn into `6F00` (unknown) instead of `6300`.

Comment: I found that the problem is my card reader. According to Paul Bastian's comment, I tried another reader, which returned success. Thanks for your all comments.